# Display number of likes next to twitter button icon

Tags: javascript, html, angular, forms

Using Angular framework. I have a button displayed in the browser that simulates a twitter button. Right now I have the number of likes goes up to 1 when it is clicked and it goes back to 0 when it is unclicked. However that likes number is being displayed in the console. I would like to display it next to the button itself, would this be a passing data to an event issue or ngContent? The first two snippets are app.component.html and app.component.ts, the second two snippets are like.component.html and like.component.ts.

```
<like [isActive]="tweet.isLiked" [likesAmount] = "tweet.likesCount"(change)="tweet.onFavoriteChange()"></like>
```

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'twitterButton';
  
  //Tweet object
  tweet = {
    body: 'Here is the body of a tweet...',
    isLiked: false,
    likesCount: 0,
    onFavoriteChange(){}
  }
}
```

```
<span class="glyphicon" 
[class.glyphicon-heart-empty] = "!isActive" 
[class.glyphicon-heart]="isActive" (click)="changeFavorite()"></span>
```

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'like',
  templateUrl: './like.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./like.component.css']
})
export class LikeComponent {
  @Input() likesAmount: number; //Total number of likes
  @Input() isActive: boolean; //User has liked tweet or not
  @Output() change = new EventEmitter();
  
  changeFavorite(){
    this.isActive = !this.isActive;
    this.change.emit();
    if(this.isActive){
          this.likesAmount++;
          console.log(this.likesAmount);
        }else{
          this.likesAmount--;
          console.log(this.likesAmount);
        }   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `{{}}`-brackets to display the number of likes, it should update automatically. This is called [interpolation](https://angular.io/guide/interpolation) and is one of the core feature of Angular.

```
{{likesAmount}}
<span class="glyphicon" 
    [class.glyphicon-heart-empty]="!isActive" 
    [class.glyphicon-heart]="isActive"
    (click)="changeFavorite()"></span>
```